# Devstack installation failing at python update.py /opt/stack/keystone

Tags: openstack, devstack

i am new learner of openstack, i am trying to install devstack on virtual box using ubunbu. while installing i am getting the following error. any one can help me. the error prompt is as follow

setup_develop /opt/stack/keystone

- local project_dir=/opt/stack/keystone
- setup_package_with_req_sync /opt/stack/keystone -e
- local project_dir=/opt/stack/keystone
- local flags=-e
  ++ cd /opt/stack/keystone
  ++ git diff --exit-code
- local update_requirements=
- [[ '' != \c\h\a\n\g\e\d ]]
- [[ strict == \s\o\f\t ]]
- cd /opt/stack/requirements
- python update.py /opt/stack/keystone
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update.py", line 38, in 
  from parsley import makeGrammar
  ImportError: No module named parsley
- exit_trap

Comment: It is very clearly telling you "No module named parsley" is the error.

Comment: I know that but how i can fix that error

Comment: Try installing the parsley module?  Possibly `apt-get install python-parsley` if you're on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by devstack. Try to update the commit and re-install, it should work. It was simply a missing library issue. You can use `sudo apt-get install python-parsley` if on Ubuntu or any Linux machine.

Another temporary workaround:

```
sudo -E pip install -U parsley
```